# Chaining Request in Combine

Tags: swift, publish-subscribe, combine

I'm struggling with combine two requests. I need `id` from the first one, then start the second one with this first `id` from the received list. I can't find a nice solution to do this with Swift Combine.

my first request looks like that `CarSerview.shared.getCategories() -> AnyPublisher<[Category], CarError>` :

```
 private func getCategories() {
    CarSerview.shared.getCategories()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map { car in
           return car.id
        }
        .replaceError(with: [])
        .assign(to: \.carsIds, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellable)
}
```

and the second one looks like that `CarSerview.shared.getCar() -> AnyPublisher<Car, CarError>`:

```
private func getCar(_ category: CategoryObject) {
    SPService.shared.getExcursions(category)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map { car in
            return car.cars.compactMap { $0.name }
        }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { error in
        print(error)
    }, receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
        self?.cars = result
    })
}
```

how can in chain this two request in one?

Comment: What value if any should pass from the first to the second? The first produces an array of car ids. Now what? Do you want to proceed with only the first car id? With all of them?

Comment: I want to pass first category to the second method

Comment: What’s a category? I see only an array of car ids coming out of the first one. And if you only need one, what happens to the rest?

Comment: In other words, pretend there is no such thing as combine. Show me how to use the second code to operate on what the first code produces. Or just tell me it doesn’t and they are unrelated sequential operations.

Comment: When using Combine, you should avoid side-effects. Declaring functions that use publishers just to then call `sink` and assign to a property is bad design. You should rather return another publisher, especially if you want to chain different methods together.

Comment: You see, if you say `assign` In the first operation. the whole pipeline is over. There is nothing to chain. So to chain them, I have to delete that. Now I am left holding an array of car ids and I don’t know what to do with it to start the second operation. Explain what you want me to do. Combine is about data flow. Flow me this data.

Comment: Why is everything called `car` in your code? You take the output of `getCategories` and bind it to `car` in a `map` transform. Is it a car, or is it a category, or an array of categories? You take the output of `getExcursions` and bind it to `car` in another `map` transform, where you call `car.cars`! Is it a car that contains cars, or is it an excursion?

Comment: Also, you say `getCategories` outputs `[Category]`, but then you operate on the output using `.map { car in return car.id }`, which cannot possibly work unless either the output is actually just `Category` or you have extended `Array` with an `id` property (which seems like a bad idea).

Answer (score 2):

Cannot test but the idea is to use .map + .switchToLatest, so can be like as follows

```
private func getCars() {
    CarSerview.shared.getCategories()
        .map { car in
            return SPService.shared.getExcursions(car.id)
        }
    .switchToLatest()
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .map { car in
         return car.cars.compactMap { $0.name }
    }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { error in
        print(error)
    }, receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
        self?.cars = result
    })
}
```